# Snap to disabled layers problem - QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, editing, snapping

I'm having some trouble with QGIS because when I try to edit a vector, it displays the edges in that point of all the layers loaded in the drawing even though they are off, making it almost impossible to proceed.
I have turned off all the snap options I could find.
Does anyone know what this could be due to or how to fix it?

Comment: Hey, welcome to GIS StackExchange. A screenshot might make it easier to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the snapping option in the snapping toolbar from `All layers` to `Active layer` to be able to snap only the target layer as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

The above option will make sure that only the target layer in the edit mode will be snapped.